# Ruby rpartition vs partition?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between rpartition and partition?
I have read the documentation but I see them like the same.
Is it just that ones came up in a later ruby version?

Answer (score 11):

The following example will help identify the difference:

```
"abccba".partition("b")
# => ["a", "b", "ccba"]

"abccba".rpartition("b")
# => ["abcc", "b", "a"]
```

So the difference is that `rpartition` searches for the rightmost occurrence, instead of the leftmost one.